# SQL Server unique-identifier equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, uniqueidentifier

What datatype should I use in C# to work with the SQL Server **uniqueidentifier**.

Do I need any conversions etc ?

Comment: This lists the equivalent .net types for all sql data types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[System.Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid)

No conversions needed.

Comment: Check this link if you have any other parameter data type mapping issues: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Answer (score 15):

System.Guid

When reading nullable Uniqueidentifier columns from your database, be sure to check if the value is null before attempting to assign to a Guid instance, as Guids are not nullable. For example:

```
... /// using recordset rs


// generates exception if rs["my_guid"] is null
Guid g = (Guid)rs["my_guid"];

// returns Guid.Empty {0000000-.....} if db value is null
Guid g = (Guid)(rs["my_guid"] ?? Guid.Empty);
```

etc.

Comment: Just use Guid? A.K.A. Nullable<Guid> and you can assign null.

Comment: That doesn't always work - ie, you'll have to wind up converting it to a non-nullable Guid at some point if you're passing to code that doesn't allow nullable Guids.

Comment: Any full source code sample using Guid? and considering DBNull != null?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the value from a SQLDataReader, make sure to check it against DBNull before you try to use it. Sometimes the value can be interpreted as a string as well, so you need to type New Guid(rs["my_guid"]) to make sure you have a guid to use in your code.

Comment: login to comment on other answers

Comment: "login to comment on other answers" you see my username and icon, right? I'm logged in, but I don't have enough reputation to comment on other's posts...